# TFS 2012 build task failed because "resgen" was not found

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to run my build for my solution in VS.NET 2012 TFS but I am getting an error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (2291): Task failed because "resgen.exe" was not found
```

I tried to install the latest Windows SDK 7.1 but it won't let me? Is there another solution for this except installing VS.NET on the build server?

Comment: You may check out the thread here talking about the resgen issue:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bef03f66-1cf3-4259-9501-52f3df992100/tfs-build-error-msb3091-task-failed-because-resgenexe-was-not-found　　Try Brandon's suggestion and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this error on my TFS 2012 Build Server (Windows Server 2012) by:

1. Installing the Windows SDK from this link:
   [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
2. Rerunning the build.

You may need to check that the following Registry Key exists (per the Build error):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx35Tools-x86
```

Comment: Here, the key didn't exist and installing the SDK created it and fixed the problem.